# Как расположить button по центру Alert Dialog переопределив стандартное поведение?

Tags: android

По умолчанию при создании AlertDialog кнопки располагаются справа. Это определено в файле: [ButtonBarLayout.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ButtonBarLayout.java)

Получается что интересует изменение строки № 149

`setGravity(stacked ? Gravity.END : Gravity.BOTTOM);` на `setGravity(stacked ? Gravity.CENTER);`

Как переопределить или создать свою функцию класс, чтобы изменить поведение кнопки по-умолчанию?

Или другим способом изменить `android:gravity="bottom"` в layout элемента:

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
android:scrollIndicators="top|bottom"
android:fillViewport="true"
style="?attr/buttonBarStyle>
    <com.android.internal.widget.ButtonBarLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layoutDirection="locale" 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:paddingStart="12dp" android:paddingEnd="12dp" 
android:paddingTop="4dp" android:paddingBottom="4dp" 
android:gravity="bottom">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button3"
style="?attr/buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
.............
```

Comment: В диалог через `setView()` можно добавить любую вью-иерархию, в которой вы можете разместить свои кнопки как душе угодно и стандартные не использовать вообще.

Comment: Либо сделать нужный `LayoutParams` и подсунуть кнопке через `setLayoutParams`

Comment: @AndreyMihalev можно поподробнее или пример

Comment: Проблема также в том, что  ButtonBarLayout в :\Sdk\platforms\android-28\data\res\layout\alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml не имеет id. А значит обращение к нему для изменения свойств не возможно

Comment: У Андроида есть своя парадигма поведения. Пользователь привык видеть кнопки справа. Зачем вам лезть "со своим уставом"?

Comment: fexbo, добраться-то до него можно и без id (например от кнопки вверх по иерархии через `getParent()`) - но в любом случае нет никакой гарантии, что на всех версиях ОС макет диалога не менялся и не будет меняться, поэтому лучше не трогать то, что не описано в публичном SDK.

Comment: @woesss я добавил в вопрос разметку. Можете предложить вариант кода с использованием getParent() ? Хотя мой вопрос по переопределению класса

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы найти `widget.ButtonBarLayout`, вложенный в `buttonPanel` используем команду:

```
val buttonPanelId = dialog.context.resources.getIdentifier( "buttonPanel", "id", "android")
val widgetButtonBarLayout = buttonPanelLayout.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
```

**Дополнительный вопрос:**

Чтобы выровнять по центру используем

```
widgetButtonBarLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
```

Но если убрать `as LinearLayout`, то *gravity* не срабатывает. Хотя изначально widget.ButtonBarLayout является "линейкой"

```
public class ButtonBarLayout extends LinearLayout {...}
```

***Почему нужно заново определять*** `val widgetButtonBarLayout` как `LinearLayout` ?

Comment: `getChildAt()` возвращает тип `View`, у которого нет такого свойства - для того чтобы получить к нему доступ и нужно приводить к типу у которого оно доступно.

Comment: Откуда такая любовь грабли самому себе раскладывать? Завтра виджет ре-дизайнят и начнет все это ваше весело падать.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо, разобрался

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja , понимаю что это возможно, но вот уже с 28 по 33 sdk ничего не меняется. А если что - всегда можно поправить